# Taking screenshot in Python not working anymore on macOS since Catalina

Tags: python, macos-catalina

I used prior to Catalina the library [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/) to make programmatically screenshots in Python.

I do not know if the OS update broke something, but since, when I do screenshots from code,

e.g.

```
# bbox declared in context
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
if os.name == 'nt':
    # Windows
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox)
else:
    # macOS (I don't worry about Linux)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox, backend='mac_quartz', childprocess=False)

# ...
im.save(filename)
```

I get a screenshot of the clean desktop instead of the apps shown on screen.

I also tried (uglier but better a thing that works than nothing)

```
os.system("screencapture %s" % filename)
```

but the same thing happens.

Is there a way to fix this situation?

Comment: could you post the error of pyscreenshot?

Comment: It doesn't give an error. It "successfully" screenshots the clean desktop instead of the apps shown in that frame (or in every other frame)

Comment: This is because of of security settings introduced in Catalina you need to allow it in security and privacy.

Comment: You need to go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` and allow your terminal under the screen recording option it should then allow you to take screenshots. See https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/134#issuecomment-567543451

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy` and allow your terminal under the screen recording option it should then allow you to take screenshots.

See [Github Issue](http://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/134#issuecomment-567543451)